# vncconfig tool allows copy/paste in one direction only on vnccserver

Tags: vnc

I have a liux debian server running a VNC Server. vncconfig is also running on the server and the connection works great, also tunneled through SSH.

But I have problems using copy/paste. When I connect to the server with my client, I can copy text from the remote server and paste it in my client, but the other way around it does not work. I really need this functionality, because I often need to copy text from the client to the server.

I tried with different VNC viewers, mainly the mac screen sharing app and with TigerVNC, same result with both of them.

I have already tried to stop / restart the vncconfig tool with and without parameters.

Comment: I have same issue between Mac (client) and Linux (server): clipboard only works from server to client. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: only "solution" was to switch to another vps hoster, there it suddenly worked. until this day i don't know why.